# How can I use the returned value of data I got from my shared preference json file as a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

how can i use this as my url parameter

userData['UserName']

I have json data in my shared preference file. So I tried to get the username
of the signed in user because I want to use as a parameter to an endpoint.

I can print the username quite ok on the console but when tried to add it
on the link, the statusCode response I get is:

```
null.
E/flutter (  906): Receiver: null
E/flutter (  906): Tried calling: []("UserName")
```

please how can I extract his username and add it to the endpoint:

Here's the endpoint that shared preference snippet that gives me the
username:

```
  var q;
  var userData;
  
  void _getUserInfo() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userJson = localStorage.getString('loginRes');
    user = json.decode(userJson);
  
    setState(() {
      userData = user;
    });
    print(userData['UserName']);
  }
```

and this is where I want to use it, on the get request link below:

```
 Future<void> get_farmer_eop() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        'http://api.ergagro.com:112/GenerateFarmersEop?farmerBvn=${widget.result}&dcOid=${widget.dc_result}&agentName=${userData['UserName']}',
        headers: _setHeaders());

    print('${response.statusCode}popo');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonStatus = jsonDecode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        q = jsonStatus['Eop'];
      });
      print('trandid');

      print('${q['TransId']}kukuk');
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  _setHeaders() => {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      };
```

But on the console I print the username and if I tried to hardcode the agentName which is the username parameter example **agentName=johndoh** it works but when **userData['UserName']** I keep getting null please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `_getUserInfo` not returning anything then why to create a separate method, try below code. It should work.

```
Future<void> get_farmer_eop() async {
  SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userJson = localStorage.getString('loginRes');
    user = json.decode(userJson);
    final response = await http.get(
        'http://api.ergagro.com:112/GenerateFarmersEop?farmerBvn=${widget.result}&dcOid=${widget.dc_result}&agentName=${user['UserName']}',
        headers: _setHeaders());
```

Comment: I actually found out the solution before i saw this. but thanks anyway. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong formatted url, try this instead:

```
final response = await http.get(
        "http://api.ergagro.com:112/GenerateFarmersEop?farmerBvn=${widget.result}&dcOid=${widget.dc_result}&agentName=${userData['UserName']}",
        headers: _setHeaders());
```